# Htmlunit - Button cannot be found

Tags: java, htmlunit

I want to click a button with this code ("..." means that it was too long to copy):

```
<a title="theTitle" id="123654" onclick="..." >Press me!</a>
```

using Htmlunit. The code I have is:

```
try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {

        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://pathToURL.html");

        HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton) page.getElementById("123654");

        System.out.println(button);
    }
```

The problem is that button is null. What is wrong with the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [API docs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlButton.html):

> public class HtmlButton extends HtmlElement
>   implements DisabledElement, SubmittableElement, FormFieldWithNameHistory Wrapper
>
> for the HTML element "button".

`<a>` is not a button, hence your program can't find it.

You want to use [`HtmlAnchor`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlButton.html) for that.

> public class HtmlAnchor extends HtmlElement
>
> Wrapper for the HTML
>   element "a".